# Sacrificing database size for performance or vice versa?

Tags: sql, database-design, coding-style

Suppose I am building a website for an online store and have a database of products. All these products have their own pages, with their own respective URLs.

If the URL can always be derived from other data in the database (let's pretend every product can be found at http://example.com/[  PRODUCT.CATEGORY  ]?prod=[  SHA1(PRODUCT.NAME)  ]), would it be wise to store the URL in another field of the table?

On one hand, it is duplicate data (it can easily be derived from other existing fields in the table). On the other hand, these URLs are used everywhere and it seems wasteful re-deriving them every single time they are needed.

Is there a best-practice for this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not store ANY urls in the database.

You should create the urls at runtime based on the data you are looking for.

The page that displays the product can ignore any fields it doestn' need.

You should also use an ID field not product.name. Unless you are trying to hide certain products from users, there is no reason to sha1 the key.

Remember using the primary key to lookup a record is the fastest way possible to get that record.

Comment: The SHA1 was just an example I thought of to show that generating the URL may be an more time-consuming operation than a simple append. But thanks, I think this is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: "using the primary key to lookup a record is the fastest way possible to get that record" - not necessarily. The fastest access path to the data depends on many things which have nothing to do with the primary key: storage format, indexing, query plan and what other keys might be available for the same operation.

Comment: @sqlvogel - While there might be specific instances where you can pull a record faster than using a PK, I've never seem one. Explain how any other indexing strategy would be faster than the integer PK lookup? In general, the fastest way to get a record is using the PK.